# Write a $ currency symbol

Tags: symbols

I want to write the $ symbol in my LaTeX file. I tried `\$` and also `\textdollar`. In both cases the dollar sign is printed but I am getting an alert.

[image: Error]

I am using Sharelatex to compile the code.

**Edit:**
Sorry but the problem was not the `$`, its a `\foodnote` with `_` symbol.  Problem solved by adding `\` before each `_` symbol.

Comment: Have you checked the line the error is referring to. If you've also tried `\$` and `\textdollar` it maybe something else that's triggering the error for example `_` or `^`

Comment: If I use `\$` both in text or in math, I get the symbol and no warning.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot you are right, the problem was not the $ but a _ symbol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already solved as the OP said in his/her edit.